# Selecting data where a column is maximum

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL table like below.

```
  ID       X     Y    Z
  1        1     1    1
  2        7     4    2
  2        9     4    3
  3        2     3    1
  4        2     2    1
  4        2     2    2
  5        3     3    1
```

I want to select X  where ( ID=2 and Y=4 and Z Maximum).
I have do this code but cant understand where to add the MAX function.

```
$check_x=mysql_query("SELECT X from Hamdun_Soft where ID='2' AND Y='4'");
```

Please help me with MySQL.

Comment: `SELECT MAX(X) X FROM ... ` is that you are looking for ?

Comment: Thanks I a looking for max(Z) where to put actually

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There already was right variant if you need **only one X** with maximum Z

```
SELECT 
  X
FROM
  Hamdun_Soft 
WHERE ID = '2' 
  AND Y= '4' 
ORDER BY Z DESC 
LIMIT 1
```

And variant with subquery if there may be **not only one X** with maximum Z.

```
SELECT 
  X
FROM
  Hamdun_Soft 
WHERE ID = '2' 
  AND Y = '4'
  AND Z = (SELECT MAX(Z) FROM Hamdun_Soft WHERE ID = '2' AND Y = '4')
```

P. S.

And don't forget what `mysql_*` family of function is deprecated now. You can use `mysqli_*` or `PDO`.

Comment: Thanks alot for describing in both way.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT 
  X
FROM
  Hamdun_Soft 
WHERE ID = '2' 
  AND Y= '4' 
ORDER BY Z DESC 
LIMIT 1
```